# Installer crash; problem can't be reported

Tags: dell, inspiron

I bought a new dell inspiron 5559 with ubuntu. When I start the laptop, it automatically starts the installation process. But the installation crashes in between and it says it will allow me to file a bug report after closing that window. Then the information is being collected. But that stops in the middle and a window appears which says, "The problem can't be reported. This is not an official ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again".
Please tell me what to do about this.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you get all your installations from [official](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) Ubuntu Sources before installing. Whether or not a crash report makes it back to Canonical is not going to help you complete the install. Try the official installs, and let us know how it went.